# How can I use the screen of a broken MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a 17” unibody MacBook Pro that is broken (the GPU and motherboard are gone). Is it possible to use its screen as an external display?

I suppose it would need some kind of specific connection to feed power to the screen as well as the video.

Comment: If you have a MacBook Pro with working guts but a broken screen, you could transplant the screen from the dead MBP onto the broken-screen MBP.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine building yourself a monitor, and the only part you have is the screen display itself. No input port, controller circuitry, nor power supply.

There are not going to be easy steps that you can follow unless you can determine the OEM of the panel and [dig up a kit and guide to provide a display assembly that drives that LCD panel](https://www.instructables.com/Old-laptop-screen-into-Monitor/).

- [Use MacBook Pro LCD Screen as a standalone monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/use-macbook-pro-lcd-screen-as-a-standalone-monitor)
- [Can my Macbook Pro's display receive inputs from other sources?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39119/can-my-macbook-pros-display-receive-inputs-from-other-sources)

Comment: Thanks!! The screen was working fine, but it really seems a lot of work and maybe money just to use it as a monitor....

Answer (score 1):

Is the screen broken? If not, you might be able to make yourself a monitor using the screen. You will need video ports and some LCD controllers. You might be able to code your own firmware for the monitor, because it might need proprietary drivers. You can practice using other screens. There is something I must advise, and that is that you will probably spend more time and money trying to build your own monitor than just buying one. If you need any more help, I’m still here!